# In Racket how do i find the length of a list using struct instead of just using only higher-order functions or recursion

Tags: list, struct, scheme, racket

I'm pretty bad at understanding data structures in Racket right now so I'm currently working on a question where all I have to do is find the length of the list.

I understand there are many ways to find the length of a list using recursion and foldr and map but I'm trying to find the length of a list a specific way right now.

Here are the details of the question;

For this question, use the following data deﬁnition:

(define-struct ls (first rest))

;; a Ls is either

;; '(), or

;; (make-ls first rest) where first is an Int and rest is a Ls.

Keep in mind that since the structure is named ls, and its ﬁelds are named first and rest,you will access these ﬁelds using ls-first and ls-rest.

Here is the question

Length. Write a function (ls-length L) that consumes a Ls and returns the number of values in it.

For example, (check-expect (ls-length (make-ls 5 (make-ls 7 (make-ls 11 '())))) 3)

Here's a common way to find the length

```
(define (length lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst)  0]
    [(cons? lst)   (+ 1 (length (rest lst)))]))
```

I however want the question solved using

```
(define-struct ls (first rest))
```

This is what I have so far but I know that this code seems very wrong, I feel my base case should be correct though.

```
(define (ls-length L)
  (cond
    [(empty? L) 0]
    [(cons? (ls-first (first L))) (+ 1 (length (rest (ls-rest))))]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remember that you can't use `cons?`, `rest` and `first` on the new data structure, only `empty?`, `ls-first` and `ls-rest` are allowed. The conditions are quite simple: the list is either empty or not empty, we don't really need `cons?`. Also, be careful when calling the recursion, the procedure is called `ls-length`, not `length`:

```
(define (ls-length lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) 0]
    [else (+ 1 (ls-length (ls-rest lst)))]))
```

Compare the above with the well-known `length` implementation:

```
(define (length lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) 0]
    [else (+ 1 (length (rest lst)))]))
```

You see what happened? we only had to replace `length` with `ls-length`, and `rest` with `ls-rest`. So simple!